# Copy and paste Tamil font from a PDF into MS Word

Tags: pdf, fonts

I am using Windows 10 and I have a PDF with Tamil text in it. Upon clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> and then 'Fonts' tab, I notice the fonts used are:

- TAB-LFS-Kamban(Embedded Subset)
- TAMLKamban ( Embedded Subset

When I try to copy the text to Word, I am seeing different kind of character.

Where can I download the above mentioned fonts? Is there any other approach to copy the Tamil text from PDF to Word?

Comment: You can also visit [this page](https://www.free-fonts.com/tamlkamban) to get more about Tamlkamban fonts.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the font [from here](http://fontsgeek.com/fonts/TAMLKamban-Normal)

About copy you can try to mark text in Word for example and set font to be any which support Tamil charset (with high probability Arial, Times New Roman have such chars)